# Kubuntu 13.04 installer crashes on manual partition setup

Tags: installation, kubuntu, 13.04

I love kubuntu, but the day I get to install a new version without issue is the day I dance naked through the streets :-(

Trying to install 13.04 on my Dell XPS. The installer starts up fine, but when I get to hard disk setup I get a problem: the installer crashes.
I have two hard disks with 12 partitions in total. When I select manual setup, I can configure the first 5 partitions without problem, but when I get to the sixt partition on the 1st hard disk, the installer crashes with the following error:

`Installer crashed`

`/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/kde_components/PartitionModel.py", line 111, in parent parentItem = childItem.parent()`

`AttributeError: 'Partition' object has no attribute 'parent'`

I've even tried not configuring the 6th partition on disk 1 and moving to disk 2 instead. When I try to configure a partition there, the installer crashes as well, but without an error (just a black screen)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and after not finding a solution I decided to fix it myself. What I did:

- open a konsole, become root and go to /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/kde_components/

  ```
  sudo -s
  cd /usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/kde_components
  ```
- open PartitionModel.py for editing:

  ```
  nano PartitionModel.py
  ```
- navigate to line 111 (navigate with pageUp, Down and the cursor keys and check where you are with Ctrl-c; nano is not the easiest). You should find something like this there:

  ```
  def parent(self, index):
      if not index.isValid():
          return QtCore.QModelIndex()

      childItem = index.internalPointer()
      parentItem = childItem.parent()

      if parentItem == self.rootItem:
          return QtCore.QModelIndex()

      return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)
  ```
- the line "parentItem = childItem.parent()" should be line 111. Change it to this:

  ```
  try:
          parentItem = childItem.parent()
  except AttributeError:
          parentItem = self.rootItem
  ```
- now the above method should look like this:

  ```
  def parent(self, index):
      if not index.isValid():
          return QtCore.QModelIndex()

      childItem = index.internalPointer()
      try:
          parentItem = childItem.parent()
      except AttributeError:
          parentItem = self.rootItem

      if parentItem == self.rootItem:
          return QtCore.QModelIndex()

      return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)
  ```
- make sure you only use spaces not tabs
- restart the installer, and it should now not crash...

Worked for me, YMMV...